# What is the relationship between Daedalus and Tomoki?

Tags: sora-no-otoshimono

She frequently appears in Tomoki's dreams as a sort of "lover." She comes to his dreams to ask him to help save her.

[image: ???]

Comment: She didn't ask him to save her. She asked him to save her "children" that is the Angeloids.

Answer (score 4):

Daedalus is a scientist from Synapse, considered as the greatest mind in all of Synapse. Their relationship was not revealed until nearing the end of the story.

> She was the one who created RULE, a device to fulfill anything one wishes. Because of this, everyone on Synapse got bored. Seeing that humans, though far inferior but enjoyed their lives through hard work, the inhabitants of Synapse decided to go into a dream like state to live as humans.
>
>  So Daedalus created the device so that Synapse people can sleep and have dream living as humans. Daedalus did that too in form of Mitsuki Sohara, Sakurai Tomoki's childhood friend.
>
>  However, Sohara had weak constitution and died very young. Daedalus then decided to create another Sohara and placed her on Earth. She also later set the Uranus Queen, Ikaros, free from her seal and sent her to Tomoki.
>
>  She is also the one behind the creation of the first generation Angeloid namely, Alpha (Ikaros), Beta (Nymph), and Delta (Astrea). The latter two also joined Tomoki's group later in the story after they were ordered to kill him by Master of Synapse. She's also the one who created Pandora Box system in the first generation Angeloid which allowed them to evolve.
>
>  Daedalus was also the one who fixed Chaos, a second generation Angeloid created by Master of Synapse.

Comment: How to hide the spoiler?